# Data analysis in a comparative way

Tags: r, dataset

I'm trying to make data analysis to huge amount of data of psychophysical task.

Well, participant should estimate if a heared sound belong to which frequency (we have 8 sounds).
So for a played sound participant should answer from 1 to 8. My csv is like :

```
Id,       Frequency,      Choice,      RT
1,        5,              6,           0.675006
2,        7,              4,           0.884836
3,        4,              5,           1.020098
4,        6,              5,           1.363385
5,        7,              5,           1.244633
6,        3,              4,           1.090888
7,        5,              4,           1.075206
8,        1,              2,           0.892913
9,        8,              6,           1.301460
10,       1,              6,           1.309400
```

What I've notice is that participant have tendency to refer comparatively with the last heard sound and their last estimate and they classify the current one as "lower" or "upper" than the previous one . Example : If I estimate that sound 5 is 4 and after that I've sound 4, I'll say, this one is lower than the previous one that i've estimate as 4 so, now i'll estimate it below 4.

What I've done until now is to calculate the mean estimatation for each frequency and see if relation between choice and frequency like that :

```
mydata = read.csv("frequency.csv") 
freq1=mydata[mydata$Frequency=='1',]
freq2=mydata[mydata$Frequency=='2',]
mean(freq1$Choice)
mean(freq2$Choice)
```

I want to emphasize the effect of the previous jugement and how it impact the current one. How should I proceed to analyse my data in that way ? I'm using R and I've all my csv ready to be processed, but i'm stuck with how to do this in terms of methodology (what data frame to extract ? how to compare with the last line ? etc ..).

Comment: The reason your question has been downvoted and not answered (probably), is that you provide *no data* and no code showing what you have tried. Since you've been a member for more that 3 years, it's really inexcusable. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then update you question based in the instructions therein.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, hope that it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still kind of a broad question, but this should get you started

```
# ALWAYS plot the data
plot(Choice~Frequency,mydata)
```

[image]

This is a simpler way to do what you started to show in your code.

```
# summarize Choice for each Frequency
aggregate(Choice~Frequency,mydata,summary)
#   Frequency Choice.Min. Choice.1st Qu. Choice.Median Choice.Mean Choice.3rd Qu. Choice.Max.
# 1         1        2.00           3.00          4.00        4.00           5.00        6.00
# 2         3        4.00           4.00          4.00        4.00           4.00        4.00
# 3         4        5.00           5.00          5.00        5.00           5.00        5.00
# 4         5        4.00           4.50          5.00        5.00           5.50        6.00
# 5         6        5.00           5.00          5.00        5.00           5.00        5.00
# 6         7        4.00           4.25          4.50        4.50           4.75        5.00
# 7         8        6.00           6.00          6.00        6.00           6.00        6.00
```

Another way to display the summaries is a boxplot.

```
# boxplot of Choice by Frequency
boxplot(Choice~Frequency,mydata)
```

[image]

If you believe that subjects can distinguish changes in pitch more easily that specific pitch, then look at the change in Choice vs. change in Frequency.

```
# plot of change in Choice vs. change in Freq
with(mydata,plot(diff(Frequency),diff(Choice)))
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, Thanks, but with the plot diff function, i've a cloud of points in all the coordinates. How it's possible to emphasize, in the same plot, the density or the number of superposed point ? (e.g., http://hpics.li/c6571d4)

Comment: Try using `jitter(...)`, as in `with(mydata,plot(jitter(diff(Frequency)),jitter(diff(Choice))))`. Or try `boxplot(diff(Choice)~diff(Frequency),mydata)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Is it possible to display the value corresponding to the jitter function (percentage or nb of points ? )